# Create a new column by reading other columns based on one column's values

Tags: r, tidyverse

I saw some similar posts but couldn't work out mine.

I have a data like below from column rate1 to ind and i wanted to create another column "outcome" to extract the value from column rate1 to rate3 depending on column ind.

I could do it with case_when but when there are 20 rates. I'm thinking there must be a way to "dynamically call" the column value??

[image]

sample code:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
rate1 = c(8, 6, 1, 10, 10),
rate2 = c(6, 2, 2, 4, 3),
rate3 = c(10, 7, 4, 8, 4),
ind = c(1, 3, 1, 2, 3)
)
```

Codes I've tried:

```
df <- df %>%
mutate(outcome = case_when(ind == 1 ~ rate1,
ind == 2 ~ rate2,
ind == 3 ~ rate3))
```

follow up question:
what if my ind contains other than 123, for example: 0, and i want to show 0 if ind == 0 as the screenshot below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppGUY.png)

sample code:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
rate1 = c(8, 6, 1, 10, 10),
rate2 = c(6, 2, 2, 4, 3),
rate3 = c(10, 7, 4, 8, 4),
ind = c(1, 3, 1, 2, 0)
)
```

Codes I've tried:

```
df <- df %>%
rowwise() %>%
mutate(outcome = case_when(ind == 0 ~ 0,
TRUE ~ get(paste0("rate", ind))))
```

and the error i have is this:
Error in get(paste0("rate", ind)) : object 'rate0' not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   rowwise() %>%
   mutate(rate0 = 0, outcome = case_when(ind == 0 ~ 0,
                                         TRUE ~ get(paste0("rate", ind)))) %>% 
                                                                      select(-rate0)
# A tibble: 5 x 5
# Rowwise: 
  rate1 rate2 rate3   ind outcome
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
1     8     6    10     1       8
2     6     2     7     3       7
3     1     2     4     1       1
4    10     4     8     2       4
5    10     3     4     0       0
```

Comment: thank you for the help~! this does work!! but i have a follow up question.. how can i add in more criteria in the mutation.. for example instead of 13123 in the ind column.. it's 13120.. i tried adding case_when inside the mutation when ind == 0, return 0.. else get(...).. it still shows error.. ><

Comment: @xiaobai5883, sorry, don't get that, can you update the question and expected output.

Comment: yes, i've updated the follow up question at the bottom of the original question.. thank you!!

Comment: @xiaobai5883, have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

One workaround is to reshape the data and create a temporary secondary data frame:

First create a row id variable to use as a key for later joining:

```
df <- mutate(df, rowid = row_number())
```

Reshape the data to long, and filter to those cases for each row id that you want.

```
df_outcome <- df %>% 
  pivot_longer(starts_with("rate")) %>% 
  separate(name, c(NA, "ind2"), sep = "e", convert = TRUE) %>% 
  group_by(rowid) %>% 
  filter(ind == ind2) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(rowid, outcome = value)
```

And then rejoin the two data frames:

```
df %>% 
  left_join(df_outcome) %>% 
  select(-rowid)

  rate1 rate2 rate3 ind outcome
1     8     6    10   1       8
2     6     2     7   3       7
3     1     2     4   1       1
4    10     4     8   2       4
5    10     3     4   3       4
```